# How to make mozilla sign my updater xpi file which has the same UID hsa my main xpi file?

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to be able to update my self-distribution firefox addon.  I have so far signed my  xpi file containing UID: xyz@text.com. But, in order for updates to work, my updater .xpi file should also have the same UID:xyz@text.com. I am able to update on firefox developer mode by turning off xpinstall.signatures.required to False. This is not reliable and I wish there is an easy to way to have mozilla sign my updater .xpi file as well without throwing the Duplicate UID found.

I looked at the two other ways to update and they seem complex. i.e via Signing API and web-ext sign.

```
In my main .xpi's manifest file, I have the below.
  "version": "1.0",
"browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "xyz@text.com",
      "update_url": "https://mydomain/files/updates.json"
    }
```

```
In my updater .xpi file, I have this.
  "version": "1.2",
"browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "xyz@text.com",
      "update_url": "https://mydomain/files/updates.json"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The answer was staring at my face. Use the "Upload New Version" and then we can upload the updater.xpi file containing the same UUID and it won't say "duplicate blahblah".